# How to remove rest of a string based on a index number?

Tags: java, string

Is there a way to remove the rest of a string based on index number in java?

Due to several reasons, replace() or split() cannot be used. I've managed to find the index of where I want to make the split. I just need to find a effective way to make it happen. I suppose if there isn't anything built in, i will have to use loop.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You should really familiarize yourself with the core JDK classes, and it doesn't get much more core than [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)).

Comment: Good point! I must have blanked out on that topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

```
s.substring(0, index);
```

This will give you the string going up to (but not including) your index.